# Aquiring continuus ping result in bash on Android

Tags: android, linux, bash, ping

Trying to get continuus (looped) ping result for getting ping timeouts only, but only have one cycle of ping, and cannot loop it:

```
ping -q -c1 google.com | awk -F'/' '{print $5}'
```

what I'm doing wrong?
Want to have code that shows result like this:

```
22.2
23.5
24.3
24.5
25.3
26.2
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
while true; do 
    ping -q -c1 google.com  \
    | awk -F"/" '{print $5}' \
    | tail -n1;
done

# or a one liner
while true; do ping -q -c1 google.com|awk -F"/" '{print $5}'|tail -n1; done
```

a simple while loop will do it.

search for "loops in bash" instead of searching to solve your specific problem.
[this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) also might help.